# How can I get the values of a column of a dataframe which are a dictionary

Tags: python, json, api, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a dictionary inside a column, but I need to get the values and update the dataframe with the info. This is my dataframe:

[image: df I got from a data from API]

```
    $type   bays    carParkDetailsUrl   id  name
0   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800491   CarParks_800491 Barkingside Stn (LUL)
1   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800468   CarParks_800468 Buckhurst Hill Stn (LUL)
2   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800475   CarParks_800475 Fairlop Stn (LUL)
3   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800444   CarParks_800444 Greenford Stn (LUL)
4   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800477   CarParks_800477 Hainault Stn (LUL)
5   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800481   CarParks_800481 Leytonstone Stn (LUL)
6   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800456   CarParks_800456 Perivale Stn (LUL)
7   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800459   CarParks_800459 Ruislip Gardens Stn (LUL)
8   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800462   CarParks_800462 South Ruislip Stn (LUL)
9   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800489   CarParks_800489 South Woodford Stn (LUL)
10  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800493   CarParks_800493 Theydon Bois Stn (LUL)
11  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800496   CarParks_800496 Wanstead Stn (LUL)
12  Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.CarParkOccupancy...   [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay,...   Place\CarParks_800480   CarParks_800480 Hornchurch Stn (LUL)
```

I need to get the yellow values and save them in the dataframe to have all the info in one dataframe.
I tried so far this:

## To get info from the API:

```
r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Occupancy/CarPark?app_id=2f7e332e&app_key=68180443ed4baffb6640824d8aa7db5c')
r = r.text
df12 = pd.read_json(r)
df12
```

## To get the info from the columns with dict ($type and bays):

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["$type", "bays", "id", "name"])
items = []
for i, row in enumerate(items["results"]):
    "$type" = row["$type"]
    bays = row["bays"]
    id = row["id"]
    name = row["name"]
    dfs.loc[i] = ["$type", "bays", "id", "name"]

dfs.head(20)
```

I got this error:
list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please post code and data, not pictures of such.

Comment: @Jame I post a sample of data, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "bays" column contains a list so first of all, you have to split it:

```
def split(x, index): 
    try:
        return x[index]
    except: 
        return None
df12['bays1'] = df12.bays.apply(lambda x:split(x,0))
df12['bays2'] = df12.bays.apply(lambda x:split(x,1))
```

Then, once you really have a column with dictionary values, then you can transform it into a dataframe. this dataframe should have the dictionary keys as the columns and its values to data.

```
def values(x): 
    try:
        return ';'.join('{}'.format(val) for  val in x.values())
    except: 
        return None
v = df12['bays1'].apply(lambda x:values(x))
dfs = v.str.split(';', expand=True)
dfs.columns = df12['bays1'][0].keys()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @ Sirine Bouslama, I tried the first part of your code but I got this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-6f2b21fc9770> in <module>
     11     except:
     12         return None
---> 13 df12['bays1'] = df12.bays.apply(lambda x:split(x,0))
     14 df12['bays2'] = df12.bays.apply(lambda x:split(x,1)).....

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'bays'

Comment: are you sure that you are using the dataframe df12 that have a column with the name bays. The error says that your dataframe does not have a column with this name.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Sirine Bouslama, it worked for bays.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple dictionary inside each cell, to get the value you can use:

```
bfs['bays'] = bfs['bays'].map(lambda kv: kv.value)
```

But it looks like it's in a list or something, so if it's just a list of one dictionary in each cell, you can use:

```
bfs['bays'] = bfs['bays'].map(lambda kv: kv[0].value)
```

Comment: I got this: Series([], Name: bays, dtype: object) but not the values, Any thoughts? Thanks @Aryerez

Comment: Maybe kv.values()[0] instead?

Comment: No :( the same result I got

Answer (score 0):

weird df :D

`df12['bays'][0][0]['$type']` gives you first entry in bays column..can do similar with others

```
df12['bays'][0][0]['bayCount'] --> 2
df12['bays'][0][1]['bayCount'] --> 45
```

Comment: I tried but I got this IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: I copied your code then ran this, if you are running the loop be sure of what you're using for i

Comment: @ Derek Eden, could you please copy all what you tried? I can't get the results. Thank you.

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted your code to get df12..then ran my code...I know you're interested in $type and bays.. you can get data in the '$type' column using df12['$type'], and in the 'bays' column using df12['bays'][0][0]['KEY YOUR AFTER']..the zeros would be the indices you loop